# Making a paid app using Youtube API

Tags: business, music

For a school project we need to make a small business start-up. For our start-up we are going to make a music app which uses the Youtube API to play the videos.

We also need to think how we can make money with the app. That's why we thought of 2 plans:

- a free app with ads
- a paid app without ads and more features.

However, the question is: can I still use the YouTube API in a free app with ads and a paid app? When I'm reading the Terms of Service, I see this:

> You and your API Clients must not, and must not encourage, enable, or
>   require others to:
>
> sell, purchase, lease, lend, convey, redistribute, or sublicense all
>   or any portion of YouTube API Services, including YouTube audiovisual
>   content;
>
> sell YouTube API Services or access to any components of YouTube API
>   Services unless you obtain YouTube's prior written approval;
>
> sell advertising, sponsorships, or promotions that are placed on or
>   within YouTube audiovisual content or the YouTube player without
>   YouTube's prior written approval;
>
> *More here:
>   https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/developer-policies#g-distribution-and-commercial-use*

I'm not selling a YouTube API service, but an application which will have more features and stuff. So, is it still possible to use the YouTube API in a free app with ads and a paid app?

Kinds Regards, Jonas

Comment: *"**You and your API Clients must not**, and must not encourage, enable, or require others to:
sell, purchase, lease, lend, convey, redistribute, or sublicense all or any portion of YouTube API Services, including YouTube audiovisual content;
**sell YouTube API Services or access to any components of YouTube API Services** unless you obtain YouTube's prior written approval;"* - how could that be more clear? You propose an obvious violation of the terms.

Comment: I wonder if this stands for in-app purchases of non-YouTube content.